# Tornado PeriodicCallback does not works when using larger callback_time (ie: 200ms)

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, rabbitmq, tornado

I have a websocket server application which sends messages to each websocket clients using Tornado `PeriodicCallback`.

```
ioloop.PeriodicCallback(dispatch, 10).start()
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The `dispatch()` function has a loop to consume RabbitMQ messages then forward them to each websocket clients.

```
def dispatch():

    global channel, queue
    time_start = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue)
            if method_frame:
                message = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))
                if 'websocket_uri' in message:
                    websocket_uri = message['websocket_uri']
                    uri = urlparse(websocket_uri)
                    path = uri.path
                else:
                    path = ''
                if 'payload' in message:
                    payload = json.dumps(message['payload'])
                else:
                    payload = ''
                for client in clients:
                    if client.path == path:
                        client.write_message(payload)
                        logger.info('WRITE: %s: %s' % (client.path, payload))
                channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(str(e))
            channel.basic_nack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
        finally:
            time_end = time.time()

        if time_end - time_start > 1:
            break;

    return
```

Somehow, when i use a larger callback_time value like 100ms or 200ms, not all messages forwarded to websocket clients. But when i use smaller value like 10ms or 1ms, the function works.

How the `PeriodicCallback` actually works? How to make sure the `dispatch()` function always called by Tornado?

Thanks

Comment: Could you insert some print statements in side `dispatch()` to check whether it's being called or not?

Comment: I did. After few hours in testing and watching the logs, i found the solution. I only need to add:

ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(dispatch)

at the end of the dispatch function and replace PeriodicCallback with the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I replaced the `PeriodicCallback` with `add_callback`:

```
app.listen(9001)
mainloop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
mainloop.add_callback(dispatch)
mainloop.start()
```

Then use `add_callback` at the end of `dispatch()` function so the `dispatch()` function will be called on the next I/O iteration.

```
def dispatch():

    global channel, queue
    while True:
        try:
            method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue)
            if method_frame:
                message = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))
                if 'websocket_uri' in message:
                    websocket_uri = message['websocket_uri']
                    uri = urlparse(websocket_uri)
                    path = uri.path
                else:
                    path = ''
                if 'payload' in message:
                    payload = json.dumps(message['payload'])
                    logger.info('Payload: %s' % payload)
                else:
                    payload = ''
                for client in clients:
                    logger.info('Path: %s' % client.path)
                    if client.path == path:
                        client.write_message(payload)
                        logger.info('WRITE: %s: %s' % (client.path, payload))
                channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)
            else:
                break;
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(str(e))
            channel.basic_nack(method_frame.delivery_tag)

    ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(dispatch)
    return
```